# Use PagedListAdapter inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android-nestedscrollview, android-paging

I have a `RecyclerView` that has a `PagedListAdapter`.

When I put the `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` the `PagedList` cannot compute the end of the list so start requests continuous burst for new data.

The main question is How should I use `PagedListAdapter` inside `NestedScrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it seems to be caused by the fact that `NestedScrollView` provides infinite dimensions and so `RecyclerView` will layout all its children. so I looked on github and found an implementation of `NestedScrollView` that solved the problem by passing `View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST` down to the `RecyclerView`:

https://gist.github.com/danaimset/abacaa50d746a4537686a08ecc33c1a9

Answer (score 0):

Based on Android documentation:

> Never add a RecyclerView or ListView to a scroll view. Doing so results in poor user interface performance and a poor user experience.

The best new way is to use MergeAdapter. It added to Recyclerview v1.2.0alpha. So add this dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha03"
```

### If you want to put two Adapters in one recyclerView, follow this Guide:

then make an instance of MakeAdapter and pass your adapters on it then set it as RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
MergeAdapter ma = new (firstAdapter, secondAdapter);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(ma);
```

### If you have a layout and Pagedlist, follow this Guide:

Then Make and Simple ViewHolder and put the first layout on it. Then make MergeAdapter then add your layout's adapter and then PagedList's adapter, then add adapter of PagedList:

```
MergeAdapter ma = new MergeAdapter();
ma.addAdaper(simpleAdapter);
ma.addAdapter(pagedListAdapter);
```

then set this mergeAdapter to recyclerView's adapter;

```
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(ma);
```